# Not sure how to write 2 different cookies

Tags: perl, cookies

I need to write 2 different cookies. This is what I'm using. Writes the first 1 but not the second. Thanks.

```
use CGI::Cookie qw();
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);#for cookie

print CGI::header(-cookie => [CGI::Cookie->new(
-name => '_SESSION',
-value => $cookiedata,
-expires=> $session_length, 
-path=>'/', 
-domain=> $owner, 
-secure=>$secure)]);

print CGI::header(-cookie => [CGI::Cookie->new(
-name => $username,
-value => $username,
-expires=> $session_length, 
-path=>'/', 
-domain=> $owner, 
-secure=> $secure)]);
```

Comment: What happens if you swap the two code parts? Is then the other one, which is then the first one, written but not the second?

Comment: [Stop using CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE)

Comment: Yes. Swapping will write the other one.

Comment: What is a better alternative to cgi.pm?

Comment: @FredGarvin — Follow the link

Comment: `my @cookies; push @cookies, CGI::Cookie->new(...); push @cookies, CGI::Cookie->new(...); ->header(-cookie => \@cookies);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [the documentation for CGI::Cookie](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Cookie). It has an example of sending multiple cookies:

> ```
> print header(-cookie=>[$cookie1,$cookie2]);
> ```

Don't set the value, then set a different value.

Set a single value, which is an arrayref containing **both** cookies.

```
use CGI::Cookie qw();
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);    #for cookie

print CGI::header(
  -cookie => [
    CGI::Cookie->new(
      -name    => '_SESSION',
      -value   => $cookiedata,
      -expires => $session_length,
      -path    => '/',
      -domain  => $owner,
      -secure  => $secure
    ),
    CGI::Cookie->new(
      -name    => $username,
      -value   => $username,
      -expires => $session_length,
      -path    => '/',
      -domain  => $owner,
      -secure  => $secure
      )

  ]
);
```